# C++ Expat XML tag support

Tags: c++, xml, expat-parser

I can't find any documentation about what the expat-parser does and does not support in terms of XML tags. I know that in the general case expat lets the event handlers (implemented by the user) deal with the tags, but specifically I would like to know if expat supports any sort of file inclusion tag.

The idea would be to extract common sections of XML into a single file and then include that file where necessary in the XML files which contain that data.

If anyone knows the direct answer to this that would be greatly appreciated, however I would also accept a pointer to some documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find any documentation, and I am left to assume that this is not possible. I would imagine the expat user could implement this themselves by defining a tag handler which will open a new XML file based on the value in the tags and call the appropriate methods on that file.